# iphone keyboard numeric mode detect

Tags: iphone, events, keyboard

Is is possible to detect when the user pushes the 123 button on a keyboard and moves to the numberic keyboard? I would like to display the inputaccessoryview only when the keyboard is in numeric mode, not when it is in the alpha mode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm away from my Mac at the moment so this is all best guess, but ...

UITextField & UITextView both implement the UITextInputTraits protocol meaning they both have a keyboardType property. You should therefore be able to add an observer to this property and when it changes test the change to see if its new type is UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation.

Give this a try:

```
// In your header
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField

// In your init or viewDidLoad function
[textField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"keyboardType" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil]

// Somewhere in your class add the following
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (textfield.keyboardType == UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation) {
        // This is where you'd add your accessoryView
    } else {
        // And this is where you'd remove it when the keyboardType changes to 
        // anything other than UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation
    }
}
```

Comment: I put in the code, the observer in the viewDidLoad method, and the actual method in the class. but it doesn't trigger it. Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you hook up the IBOutlet property to the UITextField in your nib?

Comment: I just tried this out for myself (*it's the first opportunity I've had*) and unfortunately it doesn't work as expected, but I did state this was best guess.

Comment: yes, connected the outlet. Thanks micpringle. I appreciate it.

Comment: No worries. It's just a shame this answer isn't the right one.